# Regex will not match all of my patterns

Tags: regex

I have been trying to get this to work and I am nearly there but can quite get the last match. This is the regex im using:

```
^`.*` (.*?)(\(.*?\))?\s
```

These are some examples of the patterns I'm trying to match

```
 1.`asgKey` tinyblob
 2.`is_asg` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL 
 3.`lastModified` datetime DEFAULT NULL
```

This regex will match 2 and 3 but not 1. I have tried adding `?` and `*` to the space char but it then doesnt match anything. I think I am misunderstanding the matching groups

`(.*?)` - match any number of characters

`(\(.*?\))?` - if there are brackets match anything inside them else ignore

`\s` - space character

group 1 is the string group 2 is the contents of the brackets if they exist

Comment: http://www.rubular.com/r/Um6RvZPHDJ works fine for me.

Comment: @codaddict, yes because the `\s` matches the newline character. If you have only the first example it will not match. [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/wi5QWjvxVO)

Comment: It doesnt work using this one http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: What do you want when there are multiple or unbalanced parentheses?  eg: \`foo\` bar(1) baz(2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're matching them one at a time, right? Then what's the `\s` meant to match for #1?

```
`asgKey` tinyblob
^  ^   ^^   ^
|  |   ||   |
` .*   `  (.*?)
```

There's nothing left, so `\s` can't match. Maybe you want `(?:\s|$)` to match a space or EOL.

That said, consider using `(\S+)` instead of `(.*?)`, as it'll only match non-spaces, and thus will do the same thing, but faster.